# UISegmentedControl's alignment get change when hiding UINavigationItem buttons

Tags: iphone, alignment, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

I have an `UISegmentedControl` in the title view of the navigation bar. Also i have right bar button(*plus*) and left bar button(*Edit*) as shown in the below image..

[image: Department button selected]

I'm hiding the two bar buttons (here, edit & plus buttons) when the ID segment is clicked. This will be like..

[image: ID button selected]

I'm using the following code to hide bar button items.

```
- (void)segmentClicked {
    segment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;  //leftBarButton is an instance of UIBarButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;  //rightBarButton is an instance of UIBarButtonItem

    if (segment == 0) {
        //Do something for segment 1 click
    }
    else if (segment == 1) {
        //Do something for segment 2 click
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
```

My problem is, when i switch from *segment1*(Department) or *segment2*(Name) to *segment3*(ID), the `UISegmentedControl` alignment get changed. How can i make it stable?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In what way does the alignment change? The text is no longer centered or the bar itself moves off center?

Comment: try to disable button don't nil it.

Comment: @PengOne When i click on the ID segment, the UISegmentedControl shrinked little in its width.

Comment: @Priyanka Just i want to know the process of hiding UIBarButton. Is there is any other good way to hide bar buttons except that assigning nil to the button?

Answer (score 1):

bar button items align automatically..
if you remove other items the segmented control will shift.
What you need to do is use a 'fixed space' bar item to position your segmented control...
instead of making your leftBarButtonItem nil, change it to a fixed space item of size required to keep the segmented control in place..
if you want to see how it works before implementing, just put a tool bar in a xib and add 'fixed space' and 'flexible space' items..

EDIT:

its pretty straight forward. Just look at the uibarbuttonitem class. create a system bar button item object of type fixed space and set it's width as per your need. and set it as your left bar button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
item.width = 50;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

EDIT 2:

another suggestion - use shorter text for the segments. like use Dept. instead of Department. if your segmented control in title view is short enough it wont be affected by bar buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Can you elaborate how to use a 'fixed space' bar item to position the segmented control by some sample code or by example links?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I did what you told.. Gave fixed width for the left bar button. But still UISegmentedControl moves :(

Comment: how are you adding the segmented control?

Comment: `segmentedControl = [ [UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department", @"Name", @"ID",nil]];
  
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
  
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
  
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;`